# Как можно в конструкторе инициализировать определенное поле массива структур

Tags: c++

Как можно в конструкторе инициализировать определенное поле массива структур?

Вот у меня есть структура вида:

```
struct MassifDataBalansir
{
    unsigned char modeWork;
    unsigned char State;
};
```

Объявляю массив

```
MassifDataBalansir massifDataBalansir[256];
```

Хочу инициализировать поле структуры `State` в конструкторе. Как это сделать?

Comment: опишите вопрос более развернуто. из вопроса не понятно о чем идет речь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct MassifDataBalansir massif = {.State=1}; // C
struct MassifDataBalansir massif = {, 1}; // C++
```

Или можно задать дефолтное значение при объявлении структуры:

```
struct MassifDataBalansir
{
    unsigned char modeWork;
    unsigned char State=1;
};
```

Comment: Это с++ 11? у меня qt4.7

Comment: Это C. В C++ можно просто задать инициализаторы по умолчанию. unsigned char State = 1;